# Removing specific items from a vector (c++)

Tags: c++, vector

I'm writing an inventory manager at the moment, it catalogs inventory based on ID number, product, quantity, and price. The code should allow the user to add an item, display inventory, and remove an item. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to remove specific items from the vectors. For this assignment, I'm not allowed to use the erase function. Can anyone help?
(I coded as much as I could, I think it works fine at the moment)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {

int cost;
int qty;
int eyeDi;
string name;
vector<string> product;
vector <int> eyeDee;
vector <int> price;
vector <int> quantity;
int option;

do
{
//MENU: add item, remove item, view items, logout
cout << "INVENTORY\n1. Add an Item\n2. Remove item\n3. View all items\n4. Logout\nEnter a number: ";
cin >> option;

switch (option)
  {
    //add item case
    case 1: 
    cout << "ADD ITEM\nProduct name: \n";
    getline(cin,name);
    product.push_back(name);
    
    cout << "Product ID#: \n";
    cin >> eyeDi;
    eyeDee.push_back(eyeDi);
    
    cout << "Price: \n";
    cin >> cost;
    price.push_back(cost);
   
    cout << "Quantity: \n"; 
    cin >> qty;
    quantity.push_back(qty);

   //remove item
   case 2:
    //PROBLEM AREA

   //display items
   case 3:
    for (int count = 0; count < eyeDee.size(); count++) {
      cout << "_________________________________\n";
      cout << "  ID      Name   Price     Qty \n";
      cout << setw(3) << eyeDee[count] << setw(10) << product[count] << setw(5) << price[count] << setw(4) << quantity[count];
    }


    //invalid
    default:
    cout << "Invalid number, try again.";
    break;
  }
}
while (option != 4);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Find an item in a vector, swap it with the last element, resize a vector with a decreased size.

Comment: Not being allowed to use `erase` sounds quiet nonsensical to me. If this is truly the case you could `swap` an item to the back of the vector and then use `pop_back`.

Comment: Take out a piece of paper. Draw a picture of a vector as a horizontal row of boxes, with some value in each box (each value in a vector). Now pick one of them and draw another vector without that value. Review both pictures until you see a pattern and a logical process for removing a value from a vector. Now write down your description of this process using short, brief, English sentences. [Have your rubber duck review your description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), then simply take your description and translate it directly into C++ code. Mission accomplished.

Comment: You need to coordinate the removal of the item from each vector based on the input, which is probably best done with ID. Search the ID vector, find the index of the target, remove that item (if you have to maintain the order of the vector, you have to shuffle every item following the target back one, otherwise do the swap and pop suggested above) - and then, go through every other vector using that index you found and conduct the same operation on it.